# Limit with modified Bessel function

Tags: calculus, limits, bessel-functions

I'm trying to determine the limit for $x\to \infty$ of the following expression:
$$
x-\frac{x-1}{x}2e^{-1/x}K_1(2/x)=x \left[1- \frac{x-1}{x^2}2e^{-1/x}K_1(2/x) \right],
$$
where $K_1(\cdot)$ denote the modified Bessel function (e.g., https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.25). My attempt:

Using the limiting form in 10.30.2 provided at https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.30, I would obtain
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
2e^{-1/x}K_1(2/x) &\sim 2e^{-1/x} \frac{1}{2}\Gamma(1)\left(\frac{2/x}{2} \right)^{-1}\\
&=e^{-1/x} x\\
&\sim \left(1-\frac{1}{x} \right) x 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
as $x \to \infty$. This would leave me with
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
x \left[1- \frac{x-1}{x^2}2e^{-1/x}K_1(2/x) \right]&\sim x \left[1- \frac{x-1}{x^2}\left(1-\frac{1}{x} \right) x\right]\\
&=x\left[1- \frac{1}{x}\left(1-\frac{1}{x} \right)^2 x\right]\\
&= x \left[ \frac{2}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}\right]\\
&\to 2.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

**QUESTION:** Is the above result correct? My intuition and some attempts to plot the function would have suggested me that the limit is $0$, so I'm wondering whether there's something I'm missing in the above reasoning. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. The function has an horizontal asymptote at $y=2$ for $x\to +\infty$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=\frac 2y$ to make the expression
$$\frac{2}{y}+e^{-y/2} (y-2) K_1(y)$$ Expanding around $y=0$ gives
$$2-y \left(\log (y)+\gamma +\frac{1}{4}-\log (2)\right)+O\left(y^2\right)$$